# richfaces with bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2, richfaces, web-frameworks

Is it possible (and reasonable) to use JSF with **richfaces** and **bootstrap** CSS styling together in one project. so using richfaces for page rendering, UI models and ajax; leaving the styling up to bootstrap and custom CSS.

Did someone ever tried this? Is this an oversized approach?

Comment: I startet over with plain JSF and Bootstrap and it worked well so far.

Answer (score 7):

I worked with richfaces 4.3 + bootstrap 3 for quite a time now and consider it a successful approach

This is, what I learned:

1. jquery version conflict: both ship with jQuery (bootstrap requires a newer version, than richfaces); doublecheck, if you are using the correct jQuery instance, especially with **$** alias!
2. richfaces skinning should be disables in web.xml
3. resources like fonts or icons, that are references from CSS are often declared as relative URL; this does not fit quite well into the JSF resource system (workaround see below)
4. JSF resource library support and versioning helps a lot with managing different JS libraries

solution for 1:

create a file **static-resource-mappings.properties** with this line

```
jquery.js=org.richfaces.staticResource/jquery-1.10.2.js
jquery-migrate.js=org.richfaces.staticResource/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js
```

in xhtml, use the resource shortcut:

```
<h:outputScript name="jquery.js"/>
```

[check this - Richfaces 4 seems to be broken with JSF 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726718/can-i-use-fixviewstate-js-from-omnifaces-with-richfaces-a4jajax-rf4jsf2-2-mo); the proposed workaround worked for me

Possible solution for 3: I added static resource servlet shipped with tomcat to web.xml and put the relative resources (query-ui theme in my project) under /static folder

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>static-resource-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>static-resource-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: due to incompatibilities, I needed to add jquery-migrate.js

Answer (score 4):

Have a look on RichFaces Bootstrap project. It's a sandbox effort but it might be useful for you.

- http://www.bleathem.ca/blog/2012/05/richfaces-bootstrap.html
- https://bootstrap-richfaces.rhcloud.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have found this project, but i'm not have still used this in any project. Look that and see if this is what you want:
https://bootstrap-richfaces.rhcloud.com/

Built on top of Bootstrap from Twitter, the RichFaces Bootstrap project is wrapping all the awesomeness of Bootstrap, all its great components, and all its effects as JSF components! It's magic and we're sure you'll love it!

Warning! This project is currently a "sandbox" project and is under heavy development. As such both tags and attribute names are subject to change at any time. Use it for fun or prototyping purposes only! But do stay tuned for the release of course!