# can i use FixViewState.js from omnifaces with richfaces' a4j:ajax (RF4+JSF2.2/mojarra)

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, omnifaces

I use the great omnifaces 1.7 workaround [FixViewState](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/scripts/FixViewState) in order to fix the following issue: viewstate and ViewScope gets lost on **ajax render="@form"**.
The workaround seems to work fine with **f:ajax** but not with **a4j:ajax** (richfaces).

Is the fix supposed to work with richfaces out-of-the-box? (richfaces version is 4.3.5)

maybe related issue logged by a4j:log:

```
error[15:09:31.667]: [status=200] During update: javax.faces.ViewState not found
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a JSF-2.2 environment?

Comment: yes - i use mojarra 2.2.5

Comment: I noticed a (maybe) related problem logged with a4j:log -> error[15:09:31.667]: [status=200] During update: javax.faces.ViewState not found << I updated my question accordingly

Comment: Yep, that's a symptom of the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tl;dnr: Richfaces-4.x is broken with JSF-2.2

**Long version:**

With regard to information from comments and from personal experience: this is a known bug with Richfaces-4.x in conjunction with Mojarra-2.2.x. See [RF-13317](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13317) for the details.

The gist is that JSF-2.2 changed to spec for the `ViewState` hidden input field and RichFaces hasn't kept up (it targets JSF-2.1, so that's fine). It still renders a JSF-2.1 viewstate id that confuses the Javascript included in Mojarra-2.2.x in that it now tries to find an element that has the JSF-2.1 viewstate id, but finds none. This makes every ajax call with RichFaces nominally *fail*, albeit in a non-destructive manner.

Personally, I use a rather ugly trick to make the above pass:

```
<o:onloadScript>
    jQuery('#viewStateContainer').html('<span id="javax.faces.ViewState"></span>');
</o:onloadScript>
<span id="viewStateContainer" style="display:none;"></span>
```

This provides RichFaces with a fake element to put the viewstate into (destroying it in the process, so it needs to be re-created by `onloadScript`).

This seems to solve my problems, but is rather confusing. So feel free to comment/ask about that.

Comment: very helpful answer! I stay tuned ... regards

Comment: I applied your trick and it seems to solve the issue... where do I have to put it ? inside form ? thx

Comment: @SteveOh I've put it into my main template (the one all other pages inherit from). Since it's plain javascript, it ought to work everywhere you put it.